# Looping until a completely reliable exception

Tags: python

Right now I'm doing this:

```
try:
    while True:
        s = client.recv_into( buff, buff_size )
        roll += buff.decode()
```

I repeatedly call `client.recv_into` until it raises an exception. Now, I know eventually, without a doubt, it *will* raise an exception...

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Is there some sort of loop-until-exception construct or a common way to format this?

Comment: You should specify what exception will occurr. That way your programm will still reliably fail if there is an unexpected error. In its current implementation even IO errors or `KeyboardInterrupts` will be swallowed.

Comment: There's no construct for this pattern specifically, because it's a pretty rare use case.

Comment: I think the way you are implementing it is a clean way, don't see the necessity of using another construct.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

Like you did

```
try:
    while True:
        s = client.recv_into( buff, buff_size )
        roll += buff.decode()
except YourException:
    pass
```

or

```
while True:
    try:
        s = client.recv_into( buff, buff_size )
        roll += buff.decode()
    except YourException:
        break
```

Personally, I would prefer the second solution as the `break` keyword makes clear what is happening in case of the exception.

Secondly, you should only catch the exception you're awaiting (in my example `YourException`). Otherwise `IOError`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit` etc. will also be caught, hiding "real errors" and potentially blocking your program from exiting properly.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be the (pythonic) way to do it. Indeed, the Python [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) page gives the following recipe for `iter_except` (calls a function `func` until the desired exception occurs):

```
def iter_except(func, exception, first=None):
    try:
        if first is not None:
            yield first()
        while 1:
            yield func()
    except exception:
        pass
```

which is almost exactly what you're done here (although you probably do want to add a `except [ExceptionName]` line in your try loop, as Nils mentioned).